# Is there a way to use a wild card for this Incrond Inotify job?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, inotify, incron

This is what I currently have:

```
/js/main.js IN_MODIFY yui-compressor -o /js/main.min.js /js/main.js
```

Is there a way to do the above for all js files and sub folders in that folder? Something like this:

```
/js/*.js IN_MODIFY yui-compressor -o /js/*.min.js /js/*.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I setup something that looks like this at the directory level. Hope this helps save time for someone else.

```
/var/www/laravel/public/js/main.js IN_MODIFY yui-compressor -o /var/www/laravel/public/js/main.min.js /var/www/laravel/public/js/main.js
/var/www/laravel/public/css/style.css IN_MODIFY yui-compressor -o /var/www/laravel/public/css/style.min.css /var/www/laravel/public/css/style.css
/var/www/laravel/app/views_original IN_MODIFY php /var/www/laravel/app/controllers/MinifyHTML.php $@/$#
/var/www/laravel/app/views_original/account IN_MODIFY php /var/www/laravel/app/controllers/MinifyHTML.php $@/$#
/var/www/laravel/app/views_original/emails IN_MODIFY php /var/www/laravel/app/controllers/MinifyHTML.php $@/$#
/var/www/laravel/app/views_original/emails/auth IN_MODIFY php /var/www/laravel/app/controllers/MinifyHTML.php $@/$#
/var/www/laravel/app/views_original/layout IN_MODIFY php /var/www/laravel/app/controllers/MinifyHTML.php $@/$#
/var/www/laravel/app/views_original/mtg IN_MODIFY php /var/www/laravel/app/controllers/MinifyHTML.php $@/$#
/var/www/laravel/app/views_original/profile IN_MODIFY php /var/www/laravel/app/controllers/MinifyHTML.php $@/$#
```